# SAS (WPS) cannot send email via SMTP. See error code

Tags: email, smtp, sas

I am using WPS, a diluted version of SAS, and I cannot send emails through the SMTP server using the normal (and fairly well documented) config flags.

I keep receiving the error message:
SSL exception: Could not initialise security context [80090322]

Having found some forum posts, the description for this issue is that the SMTP server is expecting authentication using a certificate. When I mentioned this to the IT team, nothing came from it. Having used SAS for a significant period, you would normally and quite simply apply some very basic information into the config file (see below).

I've been given the admin username and password, I've used an array of different ports, but still the same error message persists.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make SAS/WPS connect to a secure SMTP? Config file is:

```
-emailsys SMTP
-emailhost 10.0.x.x
-emailport 23 (Port 23 was opened for my use, we are not able to use port 25).
```

The error message persists even if I force the credentials via -emailid and -emailpw.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: Can you send email from the server that SAS is running on using any mail tools?

Comment: Hi, it turns out the issue was that the Fully Qualified Domain Name hadn't been supplied in the cfg file. The issue was resolved once the format server.domain.com had been applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is to utilise a fully qualified domain name, rather than an IP address or other method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I had a really bad time trying to figure this same problem out and I'd like to post my solution here for people who might need it in the future.

Basically, this problem happens because SAS/WPS is trying to validate the certificate he has gotten from the smtp server when trying to interact with it (ie.: send an e-mail).

There are 2 solutions:

- You can define the location were the trusted certificators are stored for the system to validate it.
- You can define the server option `TLS_HOSTVALIDATION` to `NONE` by doing something like `OPTIONS TLS_HOSTVALIDATION=NONE`

I hope this helps.